# Text to HTML string parsing a la Reddit Comments

Tags: regex, parsing, reddit

I've been poking through the source code for Reddit (https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki) for the past few hours and I can't find what I'm looking for: the function that does the flat text to HTML conversion for their comments.

If you're not familiar, on the site it has a table showing you how to format your comment and converts your plain text into html for links, bold, italic, etc.

**Link:** http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/rupkj/5000_artists_line_up_for_a_pirate_bay_promotion/c48sy1v *(Hit "reply" then "formatting help" to see the table of formatting options.)*

**Sample input:**

```
This should be: **bold** and **I'm also bold**

This should be: *italic* and *I'm italic too*

This should be: ~~strikethrough text~~

This should be: [A Link To Google.com](http://www.google.com)

This should be A list:
*This is a list
*Of differnet
*Things that I like
```

Any idea how to accomplish this elegantly with regex?

Comment: Are you looking for a [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) parser?

Comment: I sure was!!!! That's *exactly* what I was looking for. Thanks Qtax!

Comment: Qtax, can you put that as an answer so I can give you Karma? :)

Comment: For those that happen upon this, I also found [this blog post](http://blog.reddit.com/2010/02/reddit-has-new-rendering-engine.html) from Reddit about their comment system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you are probably looking for [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).